# Linux terminal - printing lots of data

Tags: c, linux, terminal

I am writing application in C programming language that enables to monitor remote computers system information, number of logged users, free memory and so on.

I will write gathered info to standard output. But usually there will be more information then  one single window of terminal, so I will need to implement some sort of 'scrolling' through results.

The easiest solution is I think to print for example first 25 rows, and then wait for user to push up or down and rewrite all rows accordingly.

Is there some easier/more elegant way to handle such output on terminal?

EDIT: forgot to mention, I would like to refresh the data if some new input comes from some remote computer, for example: number of processes changes.

Comment: What about printing it all and using a pager like less to scroll the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you need curses.

Here's a [guide to the `ncurses` library](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/).

It's an old school GUI library for terminals. Things like `top` and `make menuconfig` use it, so it's on every system. It allows you to stop thinking in terms of "print 25 lines and refresh" and more in terms of "put data in the text area which is scrollable".

Comment: You say srollable text area, but doing this scrollable panel would consist of creating a Ncurses window, printing strings and then listening for user input and then moving everything one line up or down and writing new one?

Comment: @Andna: Depends on what you're doing, you don't have to write a new one. You can get a `pad` with `newpad` and change its position (one function call).

Answer (score 3):

Use an external pager, such as `more` (or `less`) to paginate the output. The strength of Unix is in combining simple commands, creating pipelines instead of reinventing functionality that already exists.